# Spherical average of solution to Poisson equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

I'm currently reading the paper "Local asymptotic symmetry of singular solutions to nonlinear elliptic equations" by Congming Li: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01232373.pdf I have a couple questions about the proof of Lemma 1. For some background, we have a non-negative function $ v $ in $H_{loc}^1(B_{2}(0) \setminus \{0\})$ and non-negative$f \in L_{loc}^1(B_{2}(0) \setminus \{0\})$ such that $$  \Delta v(x) +f(x) =0,\hspace{0.5 cm} B_{2}(0) \setminus \{0\}.$$  The author then goes on to show that this implies $f \in L^1(B_{1}(0))$ (this is fine). Now, letting $\bar v(r)$ and $\bar f(r) $ be the spherical averages of $v$ and $f$ over the balls of radius $r$, we have $$ (10) \hspace{1 cm} \Delta \bar v(x) + \bar f(x) = 0, \hspace{0.5 cm} B_{2}(0) \setminus \{0\}.$$ By multiplying the above equation (10) by $r^{n-1}$ and integrating by parts , we arrive at $$ r^{n-1}\bar v'(r) = (n-2)m_{1} + o(1) $$ as $r \to 0$, where $$ m_{1} = \frac{-1}{n-2}\bigg(\bar v'(1) + \frac{1}{\mu(S)}\int_{B_{1}(0)}f(x)dx \bigg),$$ where $S$ is the unit sphere and $\mu$ is the induced area measure on $(n-1)$ dimensional surfaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The author then claims we have $$ r^{n-2} \bar v(r) = m_{1} +o(1).$$ I tried dividing the previous equation by $r^{n-1}$, integrating, and then multiplying by $r^{n-2}$, but it seems like the $o(1)$ is presenting an issue. Then the author claims that these two estimates imply that for any test function $\psi \in C^{\infty}_{0}(B_{1}(0))$, $$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{B_{1}(0) \setminus B_{\epsilon}(0)} v(x)\Delta\psi(x) =  - m\psi(0)- \int_{B_{1}(0)}\psi(x)f(x) , $$ which I also do not see. I tried integrating by parts / using Green's identities, but I suspect we can't use $\psi$ as a valid function to test the equation against in $ B_{1}(0) \setminus B_{\epsilon}(0) ,$ because we're really integrating the discontinuous $ \psi(x)1_{B_{\epsilon}(0)^c}.$ Appreciate if someone could resolve these two issues.